# Javascript Proxy: Modify array target and update array (length, content)

Tags: javascript, arrays, proxy

I'm proxying an array and modifying the array based on some conditions to maintain data integrity, but the array does not place nice when it's modified from the proxy.

The issues I'm experiencing is that proxied array gets polluted with ***undefined***s.

How do you update the target object to be correct if it's modified?

Here's an example pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOPLZg (the nulls are actually undefined values if you look at the console).

Work in Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit)

```
var test = new Proxy([], {
  set: function(target, name, value, receiver) {
    if(name != 'length'){

      console.log(name, target)

      // I want to overwrite values
      var i = target.indexOf(value)
      if(i > -1){
        // doesn't work
        target.splice(parseInt(name, 10), 1);

        // doesn't work
        delete target[name];

        target[i] = value;
      }else{
        target[name] = value;
      }
    }else{
      target[name] = value;
    }
    console.log(target);
    return true;
  }
});

function log(){
  $('.log').append('<br/>' + JSON.stringify(test) + test.length);
}

log();
test.push('what', 'hi', 'yo');
log();
test.push('what', 'yo');
log();
test.splice(0, test.length)
log();
```

**Submitted bug here**
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=638414#

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve. You say you want to overwrite values in a comment, but only if the value is in the array you want to overwrite it with the same value? Wouldn't that leave the array unchanged. It seems like you are trying to implement your own [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) or something, but it's not very clear. What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: @Paulpro Obviously this is just an example for purposes of demonstrating that the array adds "undefined" values. In practice, the ideas is to merge incoming data by ids if it exists. There's no point in going into that, as this example demonstrates how "unchanging" the array still adds "undefined" values into the array. The purpose of this question is to ask "why are there undefined values" or better "how to stop it from happening".

Comment: To answer your question, the final array should be ['what', 'hi', 'yo']. Instead it's ['what', 'hi', 'yo', undefined, undefined].

Comment: It's worth nothing that I believe this has to do with the internal 'length' attribute on the target. Which in another test I tried modifying. That works until you try and perform an splice or some other array function that bypasses the 'set proxy'.

Comment: I see, I just got confused by the overwriting with the same value. I have an answer coming your way.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (name != 'length')
{
    // ...
} else {
    // Your trouble is the next line. Comment it to test
    // But i don't understand why.
    target[name] = value;
}
```

Comment: Ah! That does work....execpt see this pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWgNdY  Using splice leaves the undefined values in there.... :headscratch:

Comment: Please explain what your code does as well. It is considered a good practice.

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj it is good practice to explain the code. But as he said, he's not real sure why it works.  What he's saying is to not do the length assignment and just return true.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is coming from the fact that [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) sets the length property ([see step 9](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.push)) on its own, and your set function handles assignments to the length property as normal assignments.

One possibly solution is to only allow assignments to length if they don't grow the array past the last element:

```
var test = new Proxy([], {
  set: function(target, name, value, receiver) {
    if(name != 'length'){

      // I want to overwrite values
      if((i = target.indexOf(value)) > -1){
        target[i] = value;
      }else{
        target[name] = value;
      }
    }else{
      if ( value <= Math.max( -1, ... Object.keys( target ) ) + 1 )
        target.length = value;
      numSkipped = 0;
    }

    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Paul, I did try doing something like this in the codebase, which works as you have you pointed out, however, if you splice the array (unknown number of items removed), we are in trouble again. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWgNdY

Comment: @SenicaGonzalez I came up with another possible solution (updated my answer). They all have caveats, like this one doesn't allow you to manually set the length to a large value if that's what you actually want, but I think it works better for you.